# How to pass information from html form to django view

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am creating a website where users can follow certain stocks and see news based on what they follow.

I have the following models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save



class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed_stocks = models.ManyToManyField(Stock, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.profile.save()

class Article(models.Model):
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = 0 )
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    url = models.URLField()
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here is my `register` view, upon signing up for the site, users are redirected to another page where they can follow stocks for the frist time :

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProfileRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password= raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect(follow_stocks_post_registration)
    else:
        form = ProfileRegistrationForm()
        return render(request, 'core/register.html',{'form':form})
```

Now, once redirected I want users to see a list of all the `Stock`s in our database and be able to follow certain ones.

```
def follow_stocks_post_registration(request):
    all_stocks = Stock.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'core/post_registration_stock_following.html', {'all_stocks': all_stocks})
```

And post_registration_stock_following.html:

```
{%  extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block head %}
    <title>Next step follow stocks</title>
{% endblock %}

{%  block body %}
    <form action ="" method="post">
        {% for stock in all_stocks %}
            <input type="checkbox">{{ stock }}
            <br/>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type = "submit"></button>
    </form>


{% endblock %}
```

This lists all of the `Stock`s correctly but how do I pass the user selected `Stock`s into another view upon sumbission of the form? Also, am I doing this all wrong, should I be using `forms.py`?

Comment: Your checkboxes need attributes for name and value.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a FormSet to save the stocks:

```
def follow_stocks_post_registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        StockModelFormSet = formset_factory(StockModelForm)
        formset = StockModelFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            request.user.profile.followed_stocks.add(form.save(commit=False))
    all_stocks = Stock.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'core/post_registration_stock_following.html', {'all_stocks': all_stocks})
```